# Aurelia Proxy does not fire setter

Tags: javascript, aurelia

js proxy setter does not get fired in aurelia. I have a config that I inject in my components:

```
const config = { prop: 'value' };
export default new Proxy(config, {
   get: function(obj, prop) {
      console.log('get ' + prop + ' = ' + obj[prop]);
      return obj[prop];
   },
   set: function(obj, prop, value) {
      console.log('set ' + prop + ' = ' + value);
      obj[prop] = value;
      return true;
   },
});
```

The getter fires when I change a property, but the setter function is not executed, even though the value in the config object changes.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue isn't an Aurelia problem, you're using a Proxy the wrong way. I have thrown together an example of a proxy setter and getter being used.

If you open up the developer console in Chrome, you can try the following code out in your browser. The important thing to note is to work with the returned proxy, not the original object. You need to work with the proxy.

```
let config = { prop: 'value' };
let configProxy = new Proxy(config, {
   get: function(target, property) {
      return target[property];
   },
   set: function(target, property, value) {
      if (value.length > 3) {
        target[property] = value;
      } else {
        throw new ReferenceError(property + ' cannot be set');
      }
   }
});

// Setting a value less than 3 characters will trigger an error
configProxy.prop = 'D';

// This is fine
configProxy.prop = 'Dwayne';
```

Comment: I don't see the difference to my example except for the if statement. I already use the proxy for later operations on the config object --> export default new Proxy ...